# Having trouble playing encrypted video files in ExoPlayer, longer than a couple seconds

Tags: android, encryption, exoplayer

I am attempting to playback video files, via ExoPlayer, that I have encrypted within my app, but anytime I try to playback a video any longer than a couple of seconds, the video will not play.

I am encrypting the media with "AES/GCM/NoPadding" encryption.

Below is my custom DataSource class that I am using with Exoplayer to play the encrypted stream:

```
class EncryptedDataSource(
    private val context: Context,
    private val datasource: DataSource,
    private val secureKey: String
) : DataSource {

    private var cipherInputStream: CipherInputStream? = null

    private var uri: Uri? = null

    override fun addTransferListener(transferListener: TransferListener?) {}

    override fun open(dataSpec: DataSpec?): Long {
        uri = dataSpec?.uri

        val encryptedFile = File(context.filesDir, secureKey)
        val inputStream = encryptedFile.inputStream()
        val cipher = EncryptUtils.getCipherForEncryptedStream(secureKey)
        cipherInputStream = CipherInputStream(inputStream, cipher)
        
        return C.LENGTH_UNSET.toLong()
    }

    override fun read(buffer: ByteArray?, offset: Int, readLength: Int): Int {
        Assertions.checkNotNull<Any>(cipherInputStream)

        val bytesRead = cipherInputStream?.read(buffer, offset, readLength) ?: 0

        return if (bytesRead < 0) {
            C.RESULT_END_OF_INPUT
        } else {
            bytesRead
        }
    }

    override fun getUri(): Uri? = uri

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun close() {
        if (cipherInputStream != null) {
            cipherInputStream?.close()
            cipherInputStream = null
            datasource.close()
        }
    }
}
```

When I play a video that's 2/3 seconds long, everything works fine and the video plays back. If the video is any longer I get stuck in a loop where the open() function gets called, followed by the read() function several times, followed by the close() function. Then the open() function gets called immediately after and this continues in a loop.

Has anyone any suggestions as to where I am going wrong? I know the encryption/decryption logic works as I have tested encrypting and decrypting the video outside of ExoPlayer just fine, and I know that short 2/3 second videos work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the following blog:

http://blog.moagrius.com/android/android-play-encrypted-video-in-exoplayer/

I was able to solve my issue.

Comment: The link is no longer available!